# rxjs `delay` makes Protractor E2E time out

Tags: angular, typescript, protractor, rxjs

When I `ng e2e` my app, I receive this error:

> Failed: Timed out waiting for asynchronous Angular tasks to finish after 11 seconds.

Below is the `app.component.ts`. Notice how it publishes 'app' 15 seconds after you subscribe to it.

I realize that [Protractor waits until there are no pending asynchronous tasks in your Angular application](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md#waiting-for-angular). Please keep reading.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as Rxjs from 'rxjs';
import * as Operators from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title: Rxjs.Observable<string>;

  constructor() {
    this.title = Rxjs.of('app').pipe(
      Operators.delay(15000)
    );
  }
}
```

Here's the corresponding change in `app.component.html`:

```
Welcome to {{ title | async }}!
```

Everything else is bone stock (these are the only changes I made after `ng new`).

This of course is a silly example. My real-life code does something useful. **I need to be able to have Observables which do not publish anything for very long periods of time** (months, in my case).

## Is there a way to use rxjs's `delay` operator in my app such that my end-to-end tests don't time out?

Or is there something I can do to signal to Protractor that it need not wait on a particular Observable?

### Things I have tried:

#### `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false)`

This does indeed cause Protractor to stop waiting, but is not a good solution because this is an Angular app and it makes everything harder.

#### `ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {...})`

This doesn't help because the long-running operation is happening through a view binding (the `{{ title | async }}`). That's not a place where I can stick a call to `ngZone.runOutsideAngular`.

Comment: What about `ignoreSynchronisation` or increasing the time out for the Protractor sync?

Comment: @demouser123 `ignoreSynchronization` does the trick! Could you post that as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I have added an answer . :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Protractor tries to sync with Angular, for example from the `$http` calls to consider the AUT stable enough to test.

You can use `browser.ignoreSynchronisation = true` at the start of your tests (either in the `confg.js` file or in the `describe` block) to stop Protractor from doing that.

Comment: This is not a solution. Wait for Angular is a useful feature that let developers implement tests without waiting for HTTP requests, setTimeouts and setIntervals manually. Disable waitForAngular will solve this problem, but will generate lots more.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much late for this but maybe other run into the same problem, i use currently rxjs 6 with angular 8.

For me it helps to switch from delay into timer, for example:

```
of(true).pipe(delay(1000));
```

runs into protractor timed out but if i change this to

```
of(true).pipe(switchMap(() => timer(1000))
```

it is working, dont know why but so i dont have to tell protractor he should not wait for angular for a simple reason he should do since i run multiple http requests. And it does pretty much the same, if we dont care the value which was passed right.

```
browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false)
```

is not required for that then. Well this is more a work arround i would prefer to use delay but not to rewrite all e2e tests for such behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with the rxjs timer, my protractor tests throw "ScriptTimeoutError: script timeout" exceptions all the time. The solution that worked for me was that I used the native selenium webdriver API on the pages with the timer. For example:

Instead of:

```
await element(by.id('question-12' )).click();
```

I used the selenium webdriver:

```
import {By} from "selenium-webdriver";
//...
await browser.driver.findElement(By.id('question-12' )).click();
```